# Exporting files with light effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I've added a few light effects in Photoshop. When I export it i.e., save a .jpg or any other format all of the layer that have the light effects applied on are coming out full black. The effects aren't being rendered/exported in the output file. How do I render the image with the light effects applied? I can see the effect applied in the Photoshop file. But the output is black.

[image: Screenshot of photoshop file][image: Output file]

Comment: You say light effects, but all I see is a group and a bunch of raster layers. Hard to say what is going on there. It seems like all of the elements coming out black are inside the group, which is unfortunately collapsed.  If you are saving the document as it is in the first image, I have no reason to believe this should happen. Could be a bug... You could try to flatten the document before the export.

Comment: I added the filter > Render > Lighting Effects to the "color balance" layer and the group which in the bottle. I tried flattening the document but again the result was all black. Also tried the Menu > Image > Duplicate option too. Same result. :(

Comment: I tried adding the photoshop file as a whole in Illustrator to see if i can do something there. But the file itself is getting imported with all the layers blacked out.

Comment: Merging the layers also resulting in the same.

Comment: If it's flattened, there's no way these very specific sections of the image change in any way on export. Did you try trashing preferences or just restarting PS? If you try restarting with and without trashing preferences, save a flattened version of the document and test that against the original document. The way it opens in AI could mean restarting won't help... It could also indicate that the file is corrupted somehow. There could still be a third reason, but I can't come up with anything else right now. — Can you dropbox link to the file?

Comment: Flattening the document makes the layers all black immediately in the work file, not even on export. I restarted PS, and all the layers which had the lighting effect opened up black... Is it possible that it could be a Bug after the recent update?

Comment: It's definitely possible it's a bug. Many "random" bugs can be fixed by trashing the [preferences](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preferences.html) look for `To restore preferences quickly using a keyboard shortcut` below the video.

Comment: File corruption doesn't seem that far fetched either if AI import gets that way too. I've not seen file get corrupted like this, but what is happening doesn't really make sense as far as I can tell from the screenshots and what you've tried. The file corruption I've seen many times is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szH1M.jpg) and when this happens, the file is basically totally ruined and the only way to get around it is to use an older backup of the file.

Comment: Yes it is definitely  file corruption issue. Deleting the preferences did not work either. I'm just going to start the work from scratch. No other go here. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem as soon as I add lighting effects to a layer it will save that layer as completely black. My work around was to drop the image size I'm now able to save with my lighting effects.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happen to me. I tried all the suggestions and nothing worked. Here is what you have to do. Before applying the Light effects. Convert the Layer into a Smart Object, that solves the issue!

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

With the original file, try **Menu Image** > **Duplicate** > check **Duplicate Merged Layers Only** option > **Ok**

Use this new document to save it as a .jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a group to all layers of which you need to export in JPEG.

You can achieve this by selecting all layers and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to make a group. Then make a copy of this group by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then select and right click on the duplicated group layer and click Convert to Smart Object option.

Hide all layers except this layer. Now Export to Jpeg.

Your issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+A to select the entire canvas, then go to Edit > Copy Merged. Paste that as a new layer in your PSD to quickly create a flat composite of all layers that should export without issue.